# DataStax Apache Kafka Connector UDT field problem from nested JSON

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, mapping, datastax, user-defined-types

Impossible to read JSON topic for writing to cassandra table with UDT type column. *(I have many columns on my topic and table, so I've used UDT type column)* Get below warning and also flatten transform doesn't help and doesn't transform. Removing `value.call.onnet` from mapping connector works.

```
[2020-12-08 00:17:12,415] WARN Error decoding/mapping Kafka record SinkRecord{kafkaOffset=358, timestampType=CreateTime} ConnectRecord{topic='account_usage', kafkaPartition=0, key={"number":943821834,"usageDate":20201108}, keySchema=Schema{STRING}, value={"startTime":20201108001019,"endTime":20201108160902,"count":142,"call": { "onnet": { "volume": 3, "unit": "SECOND", "amount": 12.5 }, "offnet": { "volume": 1, "unit": "SECOND", "amount": 2.0 } }, "message": { "roaming": { "volume": 1, "unit": "MSG", "amount": 1.5 }, "local": { "volume": 12, "unit": "MSG", "amount": 3.0 } }, valueSchema=Schema{STRING}, timestamp=1607370857363, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}: Required field 'value.call.onnet' (mapped to column onnet) was missing from record (or may refer to an invalid function). Please remove it from the mapping. (com.datastax.oss.kafka.sink.CassandraSinkTask)
```

#### Kafka topic sample - account_usage

**Key**

```json
{
  "number": 943821834,
  "usageDate": 20201108
}
```

**Value**

```json
{
  "startTime": 20201108001019,
  "endTime": 20201108160902,
  "count": 142,
  "call": {
    "onnet": {
      "volume": 3,
      "unit": "SECOND",
      "amount": 12.5
    },
    "offnet": {
      "volume": 1,
      "unit": "SECOND",
      "amount": 2.0
    }
  },
  "message": {
    "roaming": {
      "volume": 1,
      "unit": "MSG",
      "amount": 1.5
    },
    "local": {
      "volume": 12,
      "unit": "MSG",
      "amount": 3.0
    }
  }
}
```

#### Cassandra UDT(User Defined Type) definition

```sql
CREATE TYPE ks_usage.usage_type (
    volume bigint,
    amount decimal
);
```

#### Cassandra table definition

```sql
CREATE TABLE ks_usage.usage_call
(
    number          bigint,
    usage_date      int,
    entry_date      timeuuid,
    onnet           usage_type,
    offnet          usage_type,
    primary key (number, usage_date)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (usage_date DESC)
```

#### Connector mapping

```http
POST /connectors HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8083
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 568

{
    "name": "usage-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.datastax.oss.kafka.sink.CassandraSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "account_usage",
        "contactPoints": "10.0.153.27",
        "loadBalancing.localDc": "datacenter1",
        "port": 9042,
        "auth.provider": "PLAIN",
        "auth.username": "testusr",
        "auth.password": "test",
        "topic.account_usage.ks_usage.usage_call.mapping": "number=key.number, usage_date=key.usageDate, entry_date=now(), onnet=value.call.onnet, offnet=value.call.offnet"
    }
}
```

#### Connector configuration - connect-distributed.properties

```txt
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
#key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
#value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

```txt
transforms=flatten
transforms.flatten.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value
transforms.flatten.delimiter=.
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank You for this very detailed description. I was debugging your problem, and it seems that Connect does not examine(propagate) inner fields.
The record that is sent to the Kafka connector has the following fields:

```
value.count, key.usageDate, value.endTime, value.startTime, value.call, value.message, key.number
```

You may note that there is a `call` field, but there are no inner fields like `onnet` or `offnet`.
Due to that fact, there is nothing to flatten. Those fields are not present, so they cannot be flattened. To solve your problem, you may consider:

1. Moving both `onnet` and `offnet` one level higher and removing the call value. If you do that, the record will contain `value.onnet` and `value.offnet`. You will be able to use the `ks_usage.usage_type`.
2. Create a `call` UDT that contains both `onnet` and `offnet`. By doing so, you will have one C* column with all `call` value. Next, in the mapping, you could do `onnet=value.call`.

Comment: I didn't understand why cannot be flattened? For 1st way I have another tables and I have to differentiate, can be ```call_onnet:{}, call_offnet:{}``` etc. I can also replace UDT columns with ```onnet_volume:bigint, onnet_amount:decimal``` etc. but I have so many columns and columns count 2 times increased.

Comment: Adding a column in the C* is not problematic. C* was designed to work well for tables with lots of columns.

Flatten is not working in your case because you are using the JSON without any schema as an exchange format. The JSON does not carry any information about its structure, and flatten does not see those inner fields. You may try to use an Avro as a schema for Kafka events. This format has the schema, so it carries more information about the data structure.